# How to split a string in chunks of eight chars?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following binary string

```
string binaryString = "110011100110011011001110011001101100111001100110110011100110011011001110001001100110011011001110";
```

Now I want to split the above string into group of 8 characters. eg.

```
11001110 11001110 11001110 11001110 11001110 11001110
```

I tried following code but not getting expected result

```
var binary = binaryString.Where((x, y) => y % 8 == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not very suitable to use `LINQ`, just a for loop is enough

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<string> groups =  Enumerable.Range(0, binaryString.Length / 8)
                                        .Select(i => binaryString.Substring(i * 8, 8));
```

Comment: Note that if it isn't an exact multiple of 8 characters, this will drop the last chunk - but: looks good other than that

Comment: of course it will work only if string length is multiple of 8

Answer (score 3):

How about like?

```
string binaryString = "110011100110011011001110011001101100111001100110110011100110011011001110001001100110011011001110";
int step = binaryString.Length / 8;
for (int i = 0; i < step; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(binaryString.Substring(i, 8));
}
```

Output will be;

```
11001110
10011100
00111001
01110011
11100110
11001100
10011001
00110011
01100110
11001101
10011011
00110110
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/jj5iku).

Comment: To correctly address this split, you need to skip more than 1 bit each loop. This should fix it:

Substring(i* 8, 8)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> bytes = binaryString.Select((c, i) => new { c, i })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.i / 8)
                        .Select(x => String.Join("",x.Select(y => y.c)))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure LINQ it's something like this:

```
var parts = Enumerable.Range(0, (binaryString.Length + 7) / 8)
                      .Select(p => binaryString.Substring(p * 8, Math.Min(8, binaryString.Length - (p * 8))))
                      .ToArray();
```

It's quite complex because it's able to "parse" ranges smaller than 8 characters. So:

```
string binaryString = "123456781234567"
```

will return 12345678, 1234567

```
(binaryString.Length + 7) / 8)
```

This is the number of parts we will have. We have to round up clearly, so "0" is a part, and "123456781" are two parts. By adding (divisor - 1) we are rounding up.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, (binaryString.Length + 7) / 8)
```

This will give a sequence of numbers 0, 1, 2, # of parts - 1

```
.Select(p =>
```

The select :-)

```
binaryString.Substring(p * 8, Math.Min(8, binaryString.Length - (p * 8))))
```

The Substring

```
p * 8
```

The starting point, the part number * 8, (so part #0 starts at 0, part #1 starts at 8...)

```
Math.Min(8, binaryString.Length - (p * 8)))
```

Normally it would be 8, but the last part could be shorter. It means the `Min` between `8` and the number of remaining characters.

With a Regex it's perhaps easier:

```
var parts2 = Regex.Matches(binaryString, ".{1,8}")
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Select(p => p.ToString())
                  .ToArray();
```

(captures groups of 1-8 characters, any character, then take the matches and put them in an array)